# Posting Code puzzle

Tags: discussion

While coding we all get into interesting problem, and solve them.
When that happen to me sometimes I extrapolate the interesting bit from the broad case, formulate it as a puzzle and send it to some co-worker, for learning pourpose, or just for fun.

Will it be of any interest to send them to SO? As they are not question per se, as I already know the solution.
If right/possible where should I send them? Most of them are in p-sql or TSQL.

Comment: You can post it in [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not Stack Overflow.

We have a Stack Exchange site devoted to [Programming Puzzles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). [If it meets their requirements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), post it there.

Comment: I read the requirements, as my idea wasn't about the shortest or the fastest code I can probably go for the popularity-contest