# Puzzle/challenge questions: do they belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am asking because I noticed a user where all his questions are basically SQL puzzles/challenges. At first, I thought that it was a clever way of not saying it was homework, and not having to show his personal attempts at solving the problem first, while avoiding the inevitable downvotes.

However, that does not seem to be the case here. In fact, quite the opposite, the user tends to post multiple answers to his own questions, which may be a separate issue, but that's not the reason for my question.

Interestingly, his questions have had mixed reception. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936479/sql-challenge-puzzle-given-a-stack-trace-how-to-find-the-top-element-at-each) is one case where it was highly upvoted, and was very well received by some very high-rep users. But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957837/sql-challenge-puzzle-how-to-generate-row-numbers-ordered-by-non-unique-values) is another case where it went the complete opposite way.

In all cases, there is no doubt that the way the question is formulated is very clear (I wish all SQL questions were as clear as his). The difference appears to simply be *who* looked at the question and whether they thought a puzzle/challenge type of question was appropriate on Stack Overflow.

One of the comments under the question that was downvoted suggested that this type of question was more appropriate on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. And [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252002/posting-code-puzzle) seems to suggest the same. However, OP responded:

> I went through some questions and answers in codegolf.stackexchange.com and I must say it does not strike me as the right fit for this kind of posts.

So, which is it? Are these types of questions welcome on Stack Overflow? If not, what would be the appropriate course of action?

And, maybe this is a bit more touchy, but is it possible that the reason for the lack of consensus in the specific case of SQL questions, is because, if we're going to be honest, most SQL questions on Stack Overflow are effectively treated/handled/answered as if they were individual puzzles/challenges, whether they are explicitly labeled that way or not?

What I mean by this, is that, unlike questions in others tags, I see very little effort by higher rep users to direct users to existing questions/answers that may help them resolve the problem themselves. In other words, very few questions get marked as duplicates (but most actually are a variation of some existing answer). So, is it possible that there is simply a different mentality in Stack Overflow's SQL community, and that it should be accepted for what it is? Meaning: that maybe puzzles/challenges are ok for the SQL tag.

#### Definition of a "puzzle" or "challenge" question

I would define it as a question that meets all the following requirements:

- No practical use to the OP or the community.
- The OP already knows the answer.
- The only purpose is to have fun challenging the community to see if they can solve the problem.

For the record, I personally don't think these types of questions belong on Stack Overflow. But given that the reaction was mixed, I wanted to get some feedback here.

Comment: that... just sounds like any other question. The op already knowing the answer doesn't make it any less of an on topic question. (though... I do find it particularly difficult to ask a high quality question already knowing the answer...)

Comment: Whether or not the question author knows the answer to the question that they are asking is irrelevant, this itself is evidenced by the ability to post self-answered questions.  That you know the answer before you post the quesiton doesn't make the question bad.  Looking at the two examples you provided, they're nothing more than a big requirements dump, which is *not* a good question (not that you couldn't ask a quality question, knowing the answer to that question).

Comment: Corner-case questions like that tend to be considered on-topic when they are entertaining and off-topic when they are a bore.  It certainly skews the "practical, answerable problem" directive in the help center, hard to see how any of this is practical, especially given that he doesn't state a specific dbase engine it is supposed to run on.  Woe the poor googler that finds one of them, that's ten minutes of his life he'll never get back.

Comment: Regarding the "very few questions get marked as duplicates" I agree with you. There are so many tedious duplicates and bad quality questions that if an interesting one comes along I'm personally not going to complain that it is presented as a puzzle.

Comment: see also: [Can we hold competitons?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377644/can-we-hold-competitons)

Answer (score 19):

Given that you've defined "puzzle question" as "a question that the author knows the answer to when they posted it" then yes, that's fine.  There's nothing wrong with posting a question you know the answer to.  That said, the question is still going to be held to the same quality requirements of any other question; the question isn't immune to any of the quality standards just because the author knows the answer (whether they post that answer or not).

The specific examples you've provided, though, are not good questions.  They're just big dumps of requirements to solve entire problems, asking people to just "do the whole thing". A question like that isn't a good question.  The second question in particular pretty clearly fails to meet the "practical" and "useful" qualities of a question - the constraints certainly appear to be entirely impractical - and as a result, the question doesn't seem to be useful. If there were a practical need for those constraints, I'd expect the question to explain them.

Answer (score 15):

I don't see "puzzle" as special case and post should be evaluated as any other one.

Based on updated definition "No practical use to the OP or the community." - such questions are not welcome and immediately qualify for "typographical error... was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers." along with downvote "...not useful". May be on-topic on CodeGolf.

SO is primarily site for answering concrete practical questions. If the puzzle comes out of a real problem - such a question is welcome (which is shown by first sample), just random "how to do this complicated thing" posts are not.

Having clear "puzzle" is essentially what MCVE is - you are expected to provide clean standalone sample that may not reflect real life usage.

Adding fluff to title/post is generally not welcome. Similar to "I have problem help me" in the title I don't see how "puzzle" is valuable in title/anywhere in the post - that alone may be a reason for downvote (also editing it out may be better approach if otherwise question is on-topic).

Not showing effort to solve in the question is reason for downvote/VTC - this is particularly painful point for self-answered questions like linked "puzzles". OP of such question should be prepared with flood of downvotes for that.

Question still need to be concrete and scoped - it is very likely linked questions are duplicate of collection of several answers.

Comment: One question I have is, if these kinds of "puzzles" are off-topic, why don't we close questions like [this one about concentric circles in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28646858/215552)? Hardly "practical" or "useful", shows no effort, and yet remains on the site. It was closed then reopened. I've voted to close again, but I expect that, like the [teardrop question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30711203/215552), it will just get protected, providing more fodder for more CSS puzzle games which do nothing for the site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan linked questions look practical to me (and by view count are quite popular) . They ask on concrete thing and have concrete answers which are easy to verify to be valid (or wrong). Lack of research is reason for downvote but it does not by itself make question worth closing.

Comment: Mike, if I was looking on how to nest circles within circles, that question would totally helpful. Maybe it's never been applicable to you directly but surely you could imagine how helpful drawing shapes in CSS could be to someone else.